# How to use Importrange in a Query and filter by dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to `IMPORTRANGE` if the condition in `column1` that is text formated ( Column1 = September 4, 2019 alas 5:10 pm ) contains the word September.

I am using the following formula. The other columns work fine because they contain just a single word. Since column 1 is not a single word it doesn't work. How can I use a condition that contains September?

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YcJh57OVzaeUfHhR-xHmvYums1KIwrbGYoRouXAE7k8/edit#gid=661495879", "Leads!A2:L30000"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE ((Col9 = 'Peugeot') OR (Col10 = 'Peugeot')) AND (Col14 = 'Septiembre')")`

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where

`contains` - A substring match. *whole* `contains` *part* is true if *part* is anywhere within *whole*. **Example:** `where name contains 'John'` matches `'John'`, `'John Adams'`, `'Long John Silver'` but not `'john adams'`.

Other alternatives are to use `matches` with a regular expression and `like` which supports two wildcards, `%` (zero on more characters) and `_` (anyone character). Please read the above reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

Working with dates within a query can become quite tricky.

**Use the `FILTER` function outside the query to filter your query according to date** as an alternative solution.

Suppose your dates column in `Leads!A2:L30000` is column `O`. Then, your formula will become:

```
=filter(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1YcJh57OVzaeUfHhR-xHmvYums1KIwrbGYoRouXAE7k8", "Leads!A2:L30000"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE ((Col9 = 'Peugeot') OR (Col10 = 'Peugeot'))"), Leads!O2:O30000 >= DATE(2019,9,1), Leads!O2:O30000 <= DATE(2019,9,30))
```

This way we filter our query results to just the month of September 2019.

Answer (score -2):

Try

Col14 matches 'September'

O